# Did the favorite tags get lost?

Tags: support, tag-watching

I just found out that I didn't have any favorite tags any more. No questions were highlighted in yellow and I had to re-add all (?) the tags. This is a bit annoying, since I actually don't know which tags I followed exactly.

Is this just me or a system-/site-wide accident?

Comment: My favorite tags are still there, but I'll see if I can ask someone to take a look at this.

Comment: @Undo Could this be some UI issue? I've just checked mine, and they *seemed* to be missing as well (i.e. they are no longer displayed in the right pane on the question list, nor did clicking the "edit" link next to it reveal any). Only clicking the [advanced tag subscriptions »](http://stackexchange.com/filters) link (shown after hitting "edit") reveals they are still there. Same applies when going via my preferences.

Comment: @Izzy: the "advanced tag subscriptions" does not work for me. But I have added new tags meanwhile.